# Spring Data Neo4j and array properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have a following SDN4 entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Value {

    @Index(unique = false)
    private Object value;

    private String description;

...

}
```

`Value.value` can contains primitive types/wrappers or Array.

According to my logic I have to add string `description` field in order to be able describe what is placed in the particular `Value.value`.

As you can see from the code above I have already added `Value.description` field that works fine in case of a non-array values.

The biggest issue is an Array value. Right now with a current schema I can't separately describe each item that is placed in the array. I can only describe array value in general.

For example I want to place the following values into `Value.value` array:

```
2G Bands
GPRS
```

and I want to provide a descriptions for them:

```
2G Bands: GSM 1800 / 900 MHz 
GPRS    : Available
```

where `GSM 1800 / 900 MHz` and `Available` are the descriptions for a corresponding values `2G Bands` and `GPRS`.

How to extend my current `Value` entity in order to support a separate descriptions for array values ?

Please note that I can't place value + description together(for example via a separator) as a single array item because I intensively use `Value.value` at my Cypher queries.

Comment: Why don't you create separate nodes for each value? That makes it much easier in the queries.
Or you could potentially have 2 arrays, where `description[i]` would be description for `value[i]`

Comment: I'd like to descrease data cardinality required for Cypher query as much as possible. this is why I prefer to play with a single value. Also it is very conviniet to use Neo4j functions for array values with Cypher. Does it make sense ? So another option is only to have a separate array for descriptions ?